# potential leak issues

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management

Firstly Please tell me what is potential leak and why it comes.

Potential leak is coming...
Here is My code

```
-(NSArray*)calculateRoutesFrom:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) f to: (CLLocationCoordinate2D) t
{
  //NSLog(@"maproute....5..");

    NSString* saddr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", f.latitude, f.longitude];
    NSString* daddr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", t.latitude, t.longitude];
    NSError* error;

  NSString* apiUrlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?output=dragdir&saddr=%@&daddr=%@&dirflg=w", saddr, daddr];
    NSURL* apiUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:apiUrlStr];
    NSLog(@"api url: %@", apiUrl);

    NSString *apiResponse = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:apiUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
  NSLog(@"what is this");
    NSString* encodedPoints = [apiResponse stringByMatching:@"points:\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"" capture:1L];

  NSLog(@"maproute....4..");


    return [self decodePolyLine:[encodedPoints mutableCopy]]; // Here is The potential leak
}
```

I tried doing this
return [self decodePolyLine:[encodedPoints mutableCopy]autorelease]; 
but it send to many time autorelease message.

What to do Please help.

```
-(NSMutableArray *)decodePolyLine: (NSMutableString *)encoded {
    [encoded replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\" withString:@"\\"
                              options:NSLiteralSearch
                                range:NSMakeRange(0, [encoded length])];
    NSInteger len = [encoded length];
    NSInteger index = 0;
    NSMutableArray *array = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSInteger lat=0;
    NSInteger lng=0;
    while (index < len) {
        NSInteger b;
        NSInteger shift = 0;
        NSInteger result = 0;
        do {
            b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        NSInteger dlat = ((result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;
        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        NSInteger dlng = ((result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;
        NSNumber *latitude = [[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lat * 1e-5] autorelease];
        NSNumber *longitude = [[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lng * 1e-5] autorelease];
        printf("[%f,", [latitude doubleValue]);
        printf("%f]", [longitude doubleValue]);
        CLLocation *loc = [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[latitude floatValue] longitude:[longitude floatValue]] autorelease];
        [array addObject:loc];
    }

    return array;
}
```

Comment: Could you also show what `decodePolyLine:` does

Answer (score 0):

You correctly diagnosed the problem, that your `mutableCopy` is never getting released. But you said `[self decodePolyLine:[encodedPoints mutableCopy] autorelease]` didn't work. It can't, though, because you're missing a set of brackets in there. The correct solution, which does the `autorelease` on the string, is:

```
    return [self decodePolyLine:[[encodedPoints mutableCopy] autorelease]];
```

You will get your too many releases if you did the `autorelease` on the resulting `NSMutableArray`, though, via something like this:

```
    return [[self decodePolyLine:[encodedPoints mutableCopy]] autorelease];
```

This latter use of `autorelease` is problematic. But, the first proposed change should fix the problem.

Having said that, I'd suggest a further simplification of the code. I'd be wary about methods that change mutable parameters that I pass to them (unless that behavior is needed for some reason, which it doesn't appear to be the case here). I'd rather see:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)decodePolyLine:(NSString *)encodedInput {
{
    NSString *encoded = [encodedInput stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\"
                                                                withString:@"\\"];

    NSInteger len = [encoded length];

    // the rest of your method here
}
```

Then you can invoke this simply as:

```
    return [self decodePolyLine:encodedPoints];
```

This also has the coincidental virtue of completely eliminating the problematic statement.

---

Unrelated to your problem, you could simplify your lines that say:

```
    NSNumber *latitude = [[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lat * 1e-5] autorelease];
    NSNumber *longitude = [[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lng * 1e-5] autorelease];
```

to be:

```
    NSNumber *latitude = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:lat * 1e-5];
    NSNumber *longitude = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:lng * 1e-5];
```

Or even better, maybe retire `NSNumber` altogether with just

```
    float latitude = lat * 1e-5;
    float longitude = lng * 1e-5;
    printf("[%f,", latitude);
    printf("%f]", longitude);
    CLLocation *loc = [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude 
                                                  longitude:longitude] autorelease];
```

Comment: I believe the root problem is an overrelease in the caller of this method - that's why the autorelease technique fails.

Comment: Not sure about that, but his proposed solution is clearly invalid, and the above answer should fix the immediate problem.